# Contact with 2 phone numbers - how to distinguish between them on WhatsApp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have what I would think must be quite a common situation - a friend has 2 phones, one for work and one for personal, and I've created a single android (google) contact with the both phone numbers in, identified appropriately.

However, WhatsApp displays this as 2 contacts with the same name and no way of distinguishing between them. If I want to add them to a group I have to guess which one it is, then go into the group and select them, then I can view more details to see if I've picked the right one.

Is there any easier way to distinguish between them in WhatsApp?

Answer (score -3):

Just save them as a separate contacts? Solves everything at minimal fuss.